# Shared library across processes

Tags: c, process, shared-libraries

I want to build something like this below, a shared library linked against two processes and when one process updates the internal structure in shared library, the other process should be able to read it.

Before doing this, I want to know if this possible?

or will shared library will be two different instances on these two different processes?

```
shared library:
---------------
 ------------- mod.c file -------
 struct p {
     uint pid,
 ...
 }

 mod_register ( uint pid, ...)
 {
  ... update struct p;
 }
```

### mod.c & mod.h --> mod.so

```
 Process A{

   mod_register(pid, etcc.. );

 }

 Process B {

 .. read struct p;

 }
```

Comment: Loading the library in a common parent (as Android for example cleverly does) could get you shared code pages, but you seem to want shared data pages.  For that you probably need explicit pages from your operating system's shared memory mechanism.  Or run the library as a third process and talk to it with some form of IPC.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to created is shared memory section. The process for doing this is system independent. Your library would create the shared memory area having some identifier using a system service. These creates a range of memory pages with that identifier that can be mapped to multiple processes. Each process using the library would then make to the same shared memory area where they can exchange data. You have to implement your own synchronization methods.

If you want the memory to be persistent (i.e. remains when no processes are accessing it), that's another system independent task.